# How to create dynamic incrementing variable using "for" loop in php?

Tags: php, variables

How to create dynamic incrementing variable using "for" loop in php?
like wise: $track_1,$track_2,$track_3,$track_4..... so on....

Comment: I hope you are not trying to emulate arrays ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) or `${'track_' . $i} = 'val';`.

Comment: ${...} is still a variable variable.

Comment: Y variable variables should be avoided?

Comment: What If I need the Value of variable previuos than the current variable? That is, ${'track_' . $i-1} can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Likely you should use an array.

Comment: @Parth: You can but you should use it like this: `${'track_' . ($i - 1)}` to keep the concatenation and the arithmetic clearly separated.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $name = "track_$i";
  $$name = 'hello';
}

print("==" . $track_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ${"track_{$i}"} = 'this is track ' . $i;  // use double quotes between braces
}

echo $track_1;
echo '<br />';
echo $track_3;

?>
```

This also works for nested vars:

```
<?php

class Tracks { 
    public function __construct() {
        $this->track_1 = 'this is friend 1';
        $this->track_2 = 'this is friend 2';
        $this->track_3 = 'this is friend 3';
    }
}

$tracks = new Tracks;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo $tracks->{"track_{$i}"};
    echo '<br />';
}

?>
```